# Maven Assembly Plugin - install the created assembly

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project that simply consists of files.  I want to package those files into a zip and store them in a maven repository.  I have the assembly plugin configured to build the zip file and that part works just fine, but I cannot seem to figure out how to install the zip file?

Also, if I want to use this assembly in another artifact, how would I do that?  I am intending on calling dependency:unpack, but I don't have an artifact in the repository to unpack.

How can I get a zip file to be in my repository so that I may re-use it in another artifact?

parent pom

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter></filter>
                    </filters>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>../packaging.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Child POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com. ... .virtualHost</groupId>
    <artifactId>pom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<name>Virtual Host - ***</name>
<groupId>com. ... .virtualHost</groupId>
<artifactId>***</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

I filtered the name out.  Is this POM correct?  I just want to bundle files for a particular virtual host together.

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I have the assembly plugin configured to build the zip file and that part works just fine, but I cannot seem to figure out how to install the zip file?

Well, the created assembly should get automatically attached to the project and then uploaded into the repository on an `install` and `deploy` goal. Can you show your pom?

**Update:** With your current configuration, I don't think that the assembly gets created as part of your build. You need to bind the `single` goal to a lifecycle phase, typically `package`:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>../packaging.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And now it should get installed/deployed properly.

> Also, if I want to use this assembly in another artifact, how would I do that? I am intending on calling dependency:unpack, but I don't have an artifact in the repository to unpack.

You can declare a dependency on an assembly (using the right `classifier` and `type` in your case) but since dependency are resolved through the repository, you'll need to solve the first step first. Then, declare something like this (where the classifier is the assembly's id):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com. ... .virtualHost</groupId>
  <artifactId>***</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <classifier>...</classifier>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think assemblies are supposed to be automatically attached to the build, but if that doesn't work, the [Maven Build Helper "attach-artifact" goal](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) attaches a specified file to be installed in the repository. I've used this plugin for installing files created by an external process like Ant or NSIS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether this could be usefull for you, but as a JAR file is basically a ZIP file plus the META-INF information, you could create your project as a jar without sources and add the xip countents in `src/main/resources` without needing any plugin configuration.

If you want your content to be in a different location, you can always do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.myzip</groupId>
  <artifactId>myzip-artifact-id</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <targetPath>.</targetPath>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>${basedir}/zipcontent</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

I f you want your artifact to be installed and being accessible in a repository you will need to set it up for the deploy phase:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html