# Maven: creating an archive (zip or jar) file containing files outside the project?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm currently working on a Maven based project in which I have unit tests that generate PDF files in, let's say "C:/result" directory (I definitely don't want these files to be created within any directory from my project).

Using the maven-assembly plugin, would it be possible to create an archive file (preferably zip or jar) that gathers the files that are thus generated in "C:/result"?

Basically, my goal would be to upload this archive as a regular artefact onto a Nexus server, every time I deploy a new version of my project.

Thx in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why the generated PDF files couldn't just go into `target`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I don't actually know why either. It's just a constraint I got from someone at work but I definitely will ask him the exact reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to define an assembly descriptor similar to:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <baseDirectory>C:/</baseDirectory>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>results</directory>
            <outputDirectory>./doc</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Save e.g. as `src/assembly/bin.xml`, it will be referred from the pom.
The pom would contain in the `build` section:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>out</id>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

see for more information [maven assembly documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html).

Comment: I achieved to create the archive file I wanted with a similiar assembly descriptor but now, I want to upload it on a Nexus server along with the other artefacts.

Comment: will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639585/maven-assembly-plugin-install-the-created-assembly

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Too bad I didn't bump into this question while browsing SO earlier. Anyway, thx a lot.